# Bare Bones WinPython?

Tags: python, windows

I downloaded WinPython to be used as a portable version of Python, but it has a lot of programs and modules I don't need. All I want is the standard library and Python itself.

The problem is I'm afraid that if I start deleting stuff wily-nilly I will mess up WinPython. So what is removable?

Comment: why don't you just download standard Python distribution then? it's available on Windows

Comment: I need a portable version of Python.

Comment: you can use `virtualenv` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple barboning could be by order of decreasing size :

```
pip uninstall mingwpy
```

`pip uninstall scipy`

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

You may then try re-installing the 'vanilla' light version of numpy using
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Then, if it's not enough:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image

pip uninstall pywin32
```

==> You should be 33% of the initial size at this point (rough guess, let us know)